# Reading order of the Bas-Lag books by China Miéville

Tags: books, suggested-order, steampunk, china-mieville, bas-lag

I know that the Bas-Lag books are not connected to each other, but I'm still worrying that I'll "miss" something if I start with *The Scar* instead of *Perdido Street Station*. The reason I want to start reading the books with *The Scar* is simply I liked its blurb more than *Perdido Street Station*.

Comment: I agree with Daniel Roseman's answer, but will note that the novels are very much written in in-world chronological order. While the main characters are more or less independent, certain notable figures, institutions and historical events are referenced/exist across the three novels. The short story "Jack" published in *Looking for Jake* may be an exception, as I believe it is coincident with *Perdido Street Station* and some period of time thereafter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't think of anything in *The Scar* that necessitates previous knowledge of *Perdido Street Station*. The story starts in the same city, New Crobuzon, but the bulk of it does not take place there and it doesn't depend on any of the events of PSS.

The only thing you might miss is the gradual unfolding of more details of the world of Bas-Lag: PSS is set firmly in one (very weird) city, whereas *The Scar* explores much more of the world outside. If you do go back to PSS subsequently (and I'd recommend it: it's slow to get going, but worth it in the end) you won't be spoiled as far as the story goes, but may be in terms of sense-of-wonder.

Note however that I'd definitely recommend reading PSS before tackling *Iron Council*.

Answer (score 2):

I've just finished reading *The Scar* again, I find it easily the best of the three novels. There are about two direct references in *The Scar* to events in *Perdido Street Station* but they're historical to the events unfolding in that narrative. You don't need to know exactly what they're references to in order to appreciate the story unfolding in Armada, in fact you need know nothing about New Crobuzon at all that isn't laid out in that story for you. You need to read **both** *Perdido Street Station* and *The Scar* to fully appreciate *Iron Council*.